# Is there a way to count the number of unique possible songs able to be created?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As in the number of permutations of musical notes, lyrics (all known languages), and so on?

I am no mathematician or musician so this might (probably) be totally stupid. Any ideas would be interesting to hear though.

Comment: Since you dont specify any song length, you can always construct a new unique song 1 second longer than all other known songs. The amount of unique songs is infinite, even with only one possible note.

Comment: Ah true. So if we constrained the question to the current average of say 4 minutes, then that would something quantifiable?

Comment: I've wondered a slightly different version of the same question.  Clearly many of the songs mentioned will essentially be identical (ie changing just one note won't do much).  How many truly different songs are there?  Of course this is somewhat subjective and one would need to come up with a precise way of formulating this.

Answer (score 0):

Any melody can be decently encoded at $128$ kbps, or $1$ MB per minute. Four minutes equals $4$ MB. So the total number of songs no longer than about $4$ minutes in length is lesser than $2^{~4~\cdot~8~\cdot~10^6}$

Answer (score -1):

At least on a cd its possible.
A digital song (not .mid song) is made out of samples.

A cd has a samplerate of 44100hz, this means 44100 samples per second (a sample has a length of 1/44100 seconds). A cd can't be true mono, so it will have one sample for the left channel and one sample for the right channel.

Each sample is a integer value from 32768 a +32767, or 65536 different values.

The cd can have at max 99 songs and each song must have at min 4 seconds.

The max amount of time a cd can hold is 79 minutes and 50 seconds.

Just assuming you make cd with a single song that fill the entire cd, the amount of cds you can make are 65536^422478000